# VS2010 - SQL CRL Deploy error - Deploy error SQL04105: The model already has an element that has the same name

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sqlclr

I have a SQL CLR project created in VS2010. It needs to run PreDeployScript.sql and PostDeployScript.sql. Both files exist in project. However, when trying to run the deploy, I get the following error messages:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\TeamData\Microsoft.Data.Schema.SqlClr.targets(96,5): Deploy error SQL04105: The model already has an element that has the same name dbo.PropertySetCollection.

This message is repeated for every single type we have. This leads me to believe that PreDeployScript.sql was not run.
Has anybody else run into this issue? Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bug in VS2010 SQL CLR deployment. It has do to with dropping / adding computed columns in pre/post deploy scripts. MS is working on a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have not changed the Solution name. If you have you will now be out of sync with the assembly name on the SQL Server. To fix this just drop all the stored procedures for the existing assembly, drop the assembly, then try the deploy again. A new assembly will be created on SQL Server with the Solution name that is in VS.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Sql Proviler to check if the PreDeploy.sql has run.

Also read this:

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/539211/db-projects-with-same-object-names-cannot-be-used-as-database-reference-error-sql04105?wa=wsignin1.0